# How do I change my ship's pilot?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So my companion Andronikos Revel had a quick chat with me via a quest, and I told him he could fly my ship.

Okay I guess, now I hear his voice from time to time while doing space missions. Is there anyway to tell him that I don't want him doing that anymore? can I change it to a different companion when I get more in the future?

I guess my big question here is, can the ship's pilot be changed without the one-time companion quest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you recruit your companions, they'll start bantering during Space missions. Andronikos is no different - had you not asked him to be your "pilot", you'd still hear his voice from time to time.

The one exception to this is that companions who don't speak basic (i.e., any companion that is subtitled, i.e., Khem Val) won't banter during Ship Missions. I'm not sure about companion droids like Scorpio. (2V-R8 and C2-N2 will never banter, despite speaking basic)

Comment: I guess this just reaffirms the fact that conversation options have absolutely no impact on the game outside of companion affection and alignment.

Comment: and that is per design. They didn't want people to feel they made a wrong choice (other than choosing an AC) and not be able to change it.  I disagree with the approach, but there are pros and cons.

Comment: There are some minor differences like gaining a few extra credits for giving more information or such. But it is usually extremely clear which the moneymaking option is.